# This page has too many server redirects Android

Tags: java, android, android-webview

I'm trying to create an Android App that will link to my friends blog.   It links fine to the home page but when I press a link on the page I get the error "This page has too many server redirects ".  Any ideas?

```
public class WebViewHelper {

    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

    //make it final so it will be accessible to setWebViewClient
    public WebView webview(final Context mContext) {

        // progress dialog
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);

        // new webview
        WebView web = new WebView(mContext);

        // web settings
        WebSettings webSettings = web.getSettings();

        // false
        webSettings.setSavePassword(false);
        webSettings.setSaveFormData(false);
        webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(false);

        // true
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
        webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);



        // other
        webSettings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
        webSettings.setRenderPriority(RenderPriority.HIGH);

        web.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
                //show the user progress percentage
                mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading... " + progress + "%");
            }
        });

        web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
                    String description, String failingUrl) {

                //if there's an error loading the page, make a toast
                Toast.makeText(mContext, description + ".", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();

            }

            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                //after loading page, remove loading page
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);

                //on page started, show loading page
                mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
                mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
                mProgressDialog.show();

            }

        });

        // return the web view
        return web;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure there is no problem with the webpage you are trying to view? Does it load fine with the native browser?

Also, in order to force the webview to handle the loading of any link clicked on the webview, you need to override [shouldOverrideUrlLoading()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29) method in WebViewClient. This is missing in your code.

PS : I wanted to post this as a comment, but posted it as an answer as I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: Hi,  Yeah it turns out it was a problem with the webpage.  Thanks.